# Create a vector in R by summing rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, criteria, sumifs

I have financial data which is currently in 15 minute intervals, but I want to convert the intervals from 15 minutes to 30 minutes before I conduct the rest of my analysis. As such, I would like to sum the traded volumes for two adjacent 15 minute intervals and take the closing price of the second 15 minute sub-interval (ie the end of the 30 minute period).

I have shown below an example of the data (df) and the desired output (df.30min) using an sapply function. This works fine for the example below, but given that I am analysing 10 years of daily data with 50 companies and 27 intervals per day the processing time is excessive, even for one year of data. I have similar issues if I try a for loop.

I am new to R so I am hoping that there is a fairly easy solution using one of the built in functions.

In my actual dataset there are 27 x 15 minute intervals (10:00-16:45).  I would like my final "30 minute" dataset to have one 15 minute interval from 13:30-13:45.  Also, there may be other anomalies where the stock exchange opened late / closed early or where a stock was put on a trading halt partway through a day.  (I have managed to map the times in my data to the correct Interval using a lookup table with a match function.)  Given the imperfect structure of my data I am after a solution that is not reliant on a complete set and perfectly even number of 15 minute intervals.  In Excel I would use a sumifs function.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  Company = rep(c("Co A", "Co B", "Co C"), each = 8),
  Date = as.Date(rep(c("2005-01-01", "2005-01-02"), times = 3, each = 4)),
  Time = as.factor(c("10:00:00", "10:15:00", "10:30:00", "10:45:00")),
  Interval = as.factor(c(1,1,2,2)),
  Interval.End = as.factor(c(0,1)),
  Close = abs(round(rnorm(24),1))*10+100,
  Volume = abs(round(rnorm(24),1))*10)

> df
   Company       Date     Time Interval Interval.End Close Volume
1     Co A 2005-01-01 10:00:00        1            0   106      6
2     Co A 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   102      1
3     Co A 2005-01-01 10:30:00        2            0   108      2
4     Co A 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   116     15
5     Co A 2005-01-02 10:00:00        1            0   103      5
6     Co A 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   108      4
7     Co A 2005-01-02 10:30:00        2            0   105     14
8     Co A 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   107      1
9     Co B 2005-01-01 10:00:00        1            0   106      4
10    Co B 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   103      1
11    Co B 2005-01-01 10:30:00        2            0   115     14
12    Co B 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   104      4
13    Co B 2005-01-02 10:00:00        1            0   106      4
14    Co B 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   122      1
15    Co B 2005-01-02 10:30:00        2            0   111     11
16    Co B 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   100      8
17    Co C 2005-01-01 10:00:00        1            0   100      2
18    Co C 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   109      3
19    Co C 2005-01-01 10:30:00        2            0   108      7
20    Co C 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   106      6
21    Co C 2005-01-02 10:00:00        1            0   109      7
22    Co C 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   108      7
23    Co C 2005-01-02 10:30:00        2            0   101      4
24    Co C 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   120      8

df.30min <- df[-which(df$Interval.End == 0),]

df.30min$Volume <-sapply(seq_len(nrow(df.30min)),
            function(i) sum(df$Volume[df$Company == df.30min$Company[i] &
                                        df$Date == df.30min$Date[i] &
                                        df$Interval == df.30min$Interval[i]]))

> df.30min
   Company       Date     Time Interval Interval.End Close Volume
2     Co A 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   102      7
4     Co A 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   116     17
6     Co A 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   108      9
8     Co A 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   107     15
10    Co B 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   103      5
12    Co B 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   104     18
14    Co B 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   122      5
16    Co B 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   100     19
18    Co C 2005-01-01 10:15:00        1            1   109      5
20    Co C 2005-01-01 10:45:00        2            1   106     13
22    Co C 2005-01-02 10:15:00        1            1   108     14
24    Co C 2005-01-02 10:45:00        2            1   120     12
```

Answer (score 0):

Using library `dplyr`, you can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(Company, Date, Time, Interval, Interval.End) %>% group_by(Company, Date, Interval) %>% summarise(Time = Time[2], Interval.End = Interval.End[2], Close = Close[2], Volume = sum(Volume))
Source: local data frame [12 x 7]
Groups: Company, Date [?]

   Company       Date Interval     Time Interval.End Close Volume
    (fctr)     (date)   (fctr)   (fctr)       (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl)
1     Co A 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   102      7
2     Co A 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   116     17
3     Co A 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   108      9
4     Co A 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   107     15
5     Co B 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   103      5
6     Co B 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   104     18
7     Co B 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   122      5
8     Co B 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   100     19
9     Co C 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   109      5
10    Co C 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   106     13
11    Co C 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   108     14
12    Co C 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   120     12
```

If your data frame is already arranged properly, you can get rid of that `arrange` part above.

Note: I am assuming there are always two intervals (0, 1) and therefore using hardcoded value of `2`. If this is not the case, you can use the proper subsetting.

Comment: That appears to work well on my actual dataset and is much faster. 
However, the intervals are not always in pairs. The exchange closes at 16:45 each day so I am assigning a 15 minute interval at 13:30-13:45. Also, there may be trading halts for a company on a given day, the exchange may open late/ closed early, etc.
 
I did not show the interval assignment in the above example code, but it is based on a lookup table where df$Time in the actual dataset has 15 minute intervals between 10:00 and 16:45.
 
Can this be incorporated into the summarise part of the code to avoid the hardcoded 2’s?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Company, Date, Time, Interval),
     list(Time=Time[2L],  Interval.End = Interval.End[2L],
          Close = Close[2L], Volume = sum(Volume)),
               by = .(Company, Date, Interval)]
#     Company       Date Interval     Time Interval.End Close Volume
# 1:    Co A 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   102      7
# 2:    Co A 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   116     17
# 3:    Co A 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   108      9
# 4:    Co A 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   107     15
# 5:    Co B 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   103      5
# 6:    Co B 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   104     18
# 7:    Co B 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   122      5
# 8:    Co B 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   100     19
# 9:    Co C 2005-01-01        1 10:15:00            1   109      5
#10:    Co C 2005-01-01        2 10:45:00            1   106     13
#11:    Co C 2005-01-02        1 10:15:00            1   108     14
#12:    Co C 2005-01-02        2 10:45:00            1   120     12
```